# How to install wireless drivers for Debian 8 on a MacBook Pro 8,2

Tags: debian, wifi, macintosh

I installed Debian 8 (Jessie) with a triple boot on my MacBook Pro 2011 15" (model 8,2). I had to add some options to grub to disable one graphic card and some other great stuff, but I finally succeded to have a graphical desktop (Wouhou !).

I'd like to install the wifi driver. I have read some topics about it:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Broadcom_wireless#b43

https://askubuntu.com/questions/166504/macbook-pro-wifi-wont-work

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43?highlight=%28b43%29#Supported_devices

But I am a little bit lost about which driver I have to install and how. The result of the lspci -vnn | grep -i net command is:

`02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4]
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)`

So, I think my Wifi card model is Broadcom 4331. According to the driver list (the third link above), I need the wl driver, but I don't know where I can find it and install it.

Can someone confirm my search results and help me about the install ?

*EDIT*: The result of the uname -r command is 3.16.0-4-amd64, and in some pages, they say I have to upgrade the kernel to 3.2, but I didn't find how to do that on Debian 8 amd64 and it seems tricky...

Comment: Your kernel is newer than 3.2; the driver for your wi-fi adapter should be `b43` (`modprobe b43` as root), but you probably need firmware for it... Check out https://wiki.debian.org/bcm43xx for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you Stephen ! So I did that:

I added this line to /etc/apt/sources.list:
`deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free`

Then, I ran this command:
`apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`

Just a reboot and it works !

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to share your ethernet connection through your WiFi (create a wifi hotspot)?

If so, you can take full advantage of your driver by downloading the broadcom driver, compiling and installing it:

(AND for those using kernel 4.7.x and having trouble with this solution):

You can clone this repository and run install.sh
https://github.com/hngouveia01/hybrid-v35_64-nodebug-pcoem-6_30_223_271

There you can find the link to download the driver and apply the patch to compile it on kernel 4.7.

Answer (score -1):

Go to [this link](http://www.lwfinger.com/b43-firmware/install_bcm43xx_firmware_5.100.138) and copy the content into a local file name `install_bcm4331.sh`

Then apply this command to this file:

```
chmod 777 install_bcm4332.sh
```

Then execute the comand:

```
sudo install_bcm4332.sh
```

If you have any question, this is my e-mail:

centosenterprise@gmail.com